# How do we retrieve a filtered list of items from an array of IDs in GraphQL?

Tags: javascript, graphql

Lets say I have an array of products in my database that looks like this

```
products:[
    {
        id: '001',
        title: 'Product 01',
        description: 'Some cool product'
        price: 50.00
    },
    {
        id: '002',
        title: 'Product 02',
        description: 'Some cool product'
        price: 50.00
    },
    {
        id: '003',
        title: 'Product 03',
        description: 'Some cool product'
        price: 50.00
    },
    {
        id: '004',
        title: 'Product 04',
        description: 'Some cool product'
        price: 50.00
    },
    {
        id: '005',
        title: 'Product 05',
        description: 'Some cool product'
        price: 50.00
    }
]
```

Now let's say I wanted GraphQL to only return products 1, 3 and 4 and I wanted to pass an array of `['001', '003', '004']` into the query so GraphQL can filter the items with those `id`s and return those 3 products.  What type of function would I need to implement on my schema to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a type for products, a query definition, and a *resolver*.

In your schema:

```
type Product {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  description: String!
  price: Float!
}

type Query {
  getProductsByID(ids: [ID!]!): [Product]
}
```

Then your resolver:

```
getProductsById: ( _, { ids } ) => {
  // use whatever ORM code is required to get the products by ID
  // ids will be an array of IDs - in your case an ID is just a String
  return arrayOfProducts
}
```

The `getProductsById` query is defined to accepts a single input `ids` which is an array of `ID`s.